# Error in terminal for libinput despite removing it (Uubuntu 18.04)

Tags: touchpad, libinput

I had `libinput-gestures` installed on my laptop running Ubuntu 18.04 using the Xfce desktop environment. When I open a terminal, it displays a message at the top:

```
property 'libinput Accel Speed' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format
```

I've since removed it per the github page instructions: https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures

I also deleted the config file in `/home/.config`.

But the error persists whenever I start up a terminal.

What do I need to do to fix this error?

EDIT:

.bashrc https://pastebin.com/ELTi8wxj

.bash_profile  (file does not exist)

EDIT 2:

SOLVED

I deleted the last line in .bashrc:

```
 xinput --set-prop 11 'libinput Accel Speed' 0.2
```

rebooted, and now the msg is gone! Thanks for the tips guys.

Comment: I would suggest checking your .bash[rc/profile] files for changes made earlier that made reference to it (ie. need reversal)

Comment: Would you please share your .bashrc and .bash_profile files?

Comment: see my edit to the post. I do not have a .bash_profile file though

Answer (score 1):

deleted the last line in my .bashrc line:

```
 xinput --set-prop 11 'libinput Accel Speed' 0.2
```

Thanks guiverc and mostafa for the advice

Comment: Please don't refer to device with id number *(i.e. `11`)* as they may very well change on reboot. Instead use the device name. I don't know your device name, so here's an arbitrary example from my configs: `xinput set-prop "DELL0768:00 06CB:7E92 Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`

Comment: I believe my device name is "Elan Touchpad" so I entered this:  `xinput set-prop "Elan Touchpad" "libinput Tapping Enabled" 1`  and it output: `property 'libinput Tapping Enabled' doesn't exist, you need to specify its type and format`

Comment: Well, this is odd for a touchpad. Anyway, this error is kind of unrelated to my comment, because you should get the same result if you gonna continue using an id instead of the name. You can check what properties  does the touchpad have with `xinput list-props "Elan Touchpad"`